# Formdata returns blank object

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I am working with angular 5, new to angular but i have worked on javascript frameworks lot.
I am stuck in one issue below is description thing that i am facing right now.

I have created form which i want to send to server on submit, I tried to append Formdata object consisting of all input field name and values but while processing request my script sends empty object.

Here is my code that wrote:

```
uploadBannerCreative(event) {

        const formData = new FormData();

         formData.append("data", "value");


        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        this._uploadService.upload(formData,headers).subscribe(
           data => {
                if(data.success == true) {

                }
             },
            error => {

            }
        ); 

    }
```

Here is service that sends data to server

@Injectable()
export class UploadCreativeService {

```
constructor(private http: Http) {

}

upload(data,headers) {

    return this.http.post('url', JSON.stringify(data),{headers:headers})
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return Response; 
        });
}
```

}

Its simple code but not working for me.
Am i missing something to include here ?

Comment: Does it help if you change it from const formData to let formData? Because I would have thought the const would stop that object from being modified

Comment: @MolikMiah since FormData is an object const wouldn't affect it in that way uness you were reassigning the entire variable.

Comment: Nope i tried both the solutions

Comment: This code works if i use it with core javascript functions 
I even tried to pass form as parameter but didn't worked at all 
Seems that there is a simple thing i am missing here :(

Comment: @JanakPrajapati are you saying that the server receives an empty payload?

Comment: I checked XHR in network it sends empty object {}

Comment: @JanakPrajapati can you post your upload service code

Comment: Yeah i did it have look at once

Comment: @JanakPrajapati I dont think you should be using JSON stringify on your data if you want to use form data

Comment: Binding is working fine just issue with formdata. i don't know why. i worked with these things so many times but never with angular + typescript

Comment: Have you tried to post the data without using JSON.stringify?

Comment: @floor: i removed that thing and tried too but didn't work. everything looks good for me 
If i try to add custom data in formdata variable and console.log it it's still showing empty object.

Comment: @JanakPrajapati can you console log the formData right have the append and copy paste that result in your question so we may see.

Comment: Man removing json.stringify worked
But i still not able to see form data in console.
But i can see my data in payload

Comment: Previously i have not used json.stringify at that time it was not working
But main issue was to add headers i guess. 
Anyways thanks for your help buddies

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
> ```

Don't do that. XMLHttpRequest and fetch will generate the Content-Type header automatically when you pass them a FormData object. Providing one manually will override that. In this case, the (required) `boundary` parameter is missing.

---

> ```
> JSON.stringify(data)
> ```

Don't do that. Pass the FormData object itself to XMLHttpRequest or fetch. It isn't an object that JSON.stringify can handle.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is too late to answer but I hope this can help someone later who comes to this post.

Just delete all the headers property, this worked for me.

If it is `FormData`, just parse it to the body,
dont wrap it with `json stringify`

Comment: why you downvote my answer, if you post a data in FormData format you dont need to send any headers on the fetch api except your data is object like what i always do if (data.constructor === Object) { opt.body = JSON.stringify(data); opt.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';} else {opt.body = data //formdata }